# Display one column in mobile view in bootstrap3 carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a carousel for product display using bootstrap3 carousel.I have 4 columns in a item. I am facing issue with displaying these items in mobile view. since i have used columns in carousel item bootstrap is aligning columns vertically in mobile view but i need to show only one product at once in mobile view. Here is the code for the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your carousel code with the 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly hide or show elements on different widths (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes). E.g. add `class="hidden-xs"` to last three elements, so just the first is visible on extra-small (<768px) devices.

**EDIT:**

Oh I didn't notice that. So maybe you could use multiple views in html and only show the desired one.

```
<div id="defaultview" class="hidden-xs">
    <!-- default carousel / more items per slide -->
</div>
<div id="smallview" class="visible-xs">
    <!-- carousel with one item per slide -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But it will totally hidden in mobile devices i wanted it to just show one column per view in mobile devices.